# CSS Drop down menu on hover flickering on page load or refresh

Tags: html, css, dropdown, flicker

I am learning HTML and CSS and I was trying to create menu button with drop down list of another menu items showing on hover. It is working fine, but there is one thing, which is not correct in my opinion. And that is fact, that this drop down menu shows up for half second after every page reload/refresh. Can somebody pls help and check, what is wrong in code I was trying to use?

Thank you very much in advance. Below is my HTML and CSS code.

```css
body{
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo{
  float:left;
  font-family: arial;
}

.logo h2{
  color:#fff;s
}

.menu_button{
  background-color: transparent;
  color:#fff;
  padding:15px;
  font-size:15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100px;
}

.right_menu{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.dropdown_menu{
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0 px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.dropdown_menu a{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown_menu a:hover{
    background-color: #000;
    color:#fff;
    transition: .3s;
}

.right_menu:hover .dropdown_menu{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>Hello world!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resetStyle.css">
  </head>
    <body>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
          <h2>LOGO</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="right_menu">
          <button class="menu_button">Menu</button>
            <div class="dropdown_menu">
              <a href="index.html">Home</a>
              <a href="#">About us</a>
              <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't replicate that problem on my own machine and I don't see anything wrong with the code, (apart from a stray character at the end of one of your style rules, but that shouldn't be causing it). Also, your code is importing a reset stylesheet which I'm not sure is part of your submitted code. (The reset should probably be imported before your styles). To get better answers you should also include what browser the issue is appearing on.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for that line importing reset style sheet, its not part of the code anymore, I have no reset style sheet in my root folder (it was just old part of the code), so the line in html should not do nothing currently...Also sorry for not mentioning browser and as I mentioned in comment below, problem occurs only in Chrome or Microsoft Edge, Firefox and IE is not flickering...

Comment: I'm afraid that the only useful thing I can say is that it works when I reproduce it on my Mac using Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and as I said, the code looks reasonable to me. I would suggest trying it on a different device if you can.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing on that flicker is the time between which the browser has downloaded and rendered the HTML, and it has downloaded interpreted and applied the CSS.

Depending on the speed of their computer, a user may or may not see the same artifact you're describing.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I am now working on my gaming PC, which is fast enough, so internet or pc speed should not be the problem. Sorry, I forgot to mention browser...Actually, it is not flickering in Firefox and Internet explorer and problem occurs when displaying page in Chrome or Microsoft edge.